# Obtain the convergence order of a succession of real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

How can the convergence order of the next succession be calculated?

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$x^*=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}= 1$$

We are looking for $p$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|x_{n+1}-x^*|}{|x_n-x^*|^p}=
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\big|\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1\big|}{\big|\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1\big|^p}=C>0$$

since by binomial series

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=1+\frac1{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)$$

we have that

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1=\frac1{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)$$

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1=\frac1{2(n+1)}+o\left(\frac1n\right)$$

and thus

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\big|\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1\big|}{\big|\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1\big|^p}=
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac1{2(n+1)}+o\left(\frac1n\right)}{\left(\frac1{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)^p}=\begin{cases}1 \quad p=1\\0 \quad p<1 \\\infty \quad p>1\end{cases}$$

thus the order is $p=1$.

Comment: I have learnt some relationed with limits

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar maybe you are looking of something else, what is the definition of "convergence order" you are referring to?

Comment: This definition:  https://screenshots.firefox.com/LFu2VdCCyALOZupX/es.wikipedia.org

Comment: I don't understand what is it $O(n)$

Comment: it is the little-o notation for Taylor's expansion, it represent something that vanishes when we take th elimit, which way have you learn to calculate limits?

Comment: I have given to solve limits or the rule of L' Hôpital or equivalent infinitesimal. Taylor, not yet.

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar then you can wirte by equivalent infinitesimal $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1\sim\frac1{2n}$$ and $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1\sim \frac1{2(n+1)}$$ and take the limit

Comment: I have other doubt could you pass a list of all equivalent infinitesimal, please? @gimusi

Comment: take a look here but be careful to use this way to solve in general, sometimes this approach can be erroneous http://www.vaxasoftware.com/doc_eduen/mat/infiequi.pdf